# UI-Grid enablefiltering not showing input box with AngularJS page

Tags: angular-ui-grid

I'm using UI-Grid 3.0 unstable on an angular page that is loading data via Restangular.  So far most of it seems to be ok.  I am using the selection module along with it and I'm having difficulty with pages that are loading the {enableFiltering: true} gridOptions in that most of the pages are not showing the input box on the grid.

I invoke the ui-grid on the html page using:

```
<div class="gridStyle" ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-selection></div>
```

and my gridOptions in my controller looks like this.

```
 $scope.gridOptions = {
    enableFiltering: true,
    data: 'data',
    columnDefs: [
        {field: 'name', displayName: 'Name'},
        {field: 'date', displayName: 'Date', cellFilter: 'date:\'MM-dd-yyyy\''}
    ],
    onRegisterApi: function (gridApi) {
        $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
    }
};
```

I honestly can't figure out why its not appearing on the page.

Comment: I have same issue. I tried to reproduce problem with ui-grid plunker example but I can't. Actually, many other things has been added into my app, so it is not easy to figure out what causes it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand 100% the problem, but I could go around it by overriding some css. The height in css were 100% and I changed them to auto.

```
.ui-grid-header-cell{
    height:auto;
}

.ui-grid-cell-contents {
    height: auto;
}
```

I hope this would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This an awful hack, but I always use the filters, so I just tracked the container that was the wrong height. I had lost hours to this trying to find the cause and using all the suggested fixes.
The container turned out to have the class "ui-grid-header-canvas", so I just set the height to 54px after the grid had sized itself.(after I set the data)

```
 $(".ui-grid-header-canvas").css("height","54px")
```

Sorry, but it works and I have a deadline..